# How to stop a subprocess?

Tags: subprocess

I am unable to make `stop-process` work. I expect that it behaves as `C-z` in a terminal so that I can later continue it with `continue-process`.

Minimal not working example:

```
(setq ptest (start-process "test" "*yes*" "yes"))
```

and then

```
(stop-process ptest)
```

returns `#<process test>` but does nothing (*i.e.* the process is still writing `y` into the output buffer `*yes*`). Especially, running `(process-status ptest)` says `run` instead of `stop`.

What I'm missing ?

Note: GNU Emacs 28.0.50 of 2021-01-20

Comment: I don't know the difference, but `simple.el` uses `delete-process` when a user manages processes from the `*Process List*` buffer; e.g., when calling `process-menu-delete-process`.

Comment: @lawlist Stopped processes can be restarted. They are just suspended. Deleted processes cannot be restarted.

Comment: There is the following phrase in the doc string of `interrupt-process`: If the process is a shell, this means interrupt current subjob
rather than the shell. Might it be that this is the reason you see no effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system, `yes` doesn't react to `SIGTSTP`, which is the signal sent by `stop-process` (rather than `SIGSTOP` as one might assume).

When you run `yes` in your terminal and shell, `C-z` is going to additionally prevent the process from having a terminal to write to -- so if the process is still running and generating output, the kernel will stop it at that point (via `SIGTTOU` as I understand it).  My guess is that that's the difference between the two scenarios.

You can use `(signal-process ptest 'STOP)` to send `SIGSTOP`.

```
 -- Function: stop-process &optional process current-group
     This function stops the specified PROCESS.  If it is a real
     subprocess running a program, it sends the signal ‘SIGTSTP’ to that
     subprocess.  If PROCESS represents a network, serial, or pipe
     connection, this function inhibits handling of the incoming data
     from the connection; for a network server, this means not accepting
     new connections.  Use ‘continue-process’ to resume normal
     execution.

     Outside of Emacs, on systems with job control, the stop character
     (usually ‘C-z’) normally sends the ‘SIGTSTP’ signal to a
     subprocess.  When CURRENT-GROUP is non-‘nil’, you can think of this
     function as typing ‘C-z’ on the terminal Emacs uses to communicate
     with the subprocess.
```

Comment: Thanks! In Ubuntu, `C-z` does put `yes` in background, so I expected the same from `stop-process`. The real-world command I want to stop is `mpv`, but it doesn't work as expect either. Do you have any command in your system which reacts to `stop-process` ? I'm surprised that `stop-process` is not a synonym of `(signal-process ptest 'STOP)`.

Comment: `top` is an example on my system.

Comment: Note that "in the background" is about job-control in a shell, and not really relevant to Emacs where everything has its own buffer.  I'll speculate that many programs simply assume that job control will be in effect and therefore that they don't need to handle `SIGTSTP` if the desired result will happen anyway by side-effect.

Comment: Apparently, [`SIGTSTP`  can be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888074/8274517), but `SIGSTOP` cannot. I can't try `top` with `start-process` because it says that the env variable `TERM` is not set properly. Anyway, thanks for the edit, didn't know the nuance between `SIGSTOP` and `SIGTSTP`.